# Why is there no SEH handler found in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, debugging

I use immunity debugger and mona.py to find SEH pointer in Windows 10. Command is `!mona seh`.

But it says no pointer is found.

I want to know what has changed in Windows 10 to protect against this memory corruption.

Comment: Why do you think that because mona returned that message that Win10 does not use SEH? Have you also tried `!mona seh -all`?